# Left Outer Join only if column exists (SQL server)

Tags: sql-server, join, where-clause

I'm using SQL Server Express and I'm trying to pull different columns from different tables using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. It's working great but only if all columns exist. So I've been reading for the past hour how to add a condition so that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is done only if column exists.

See code below ( the issue is the last `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because `a.[Page Path]` doesn't exist):

```
SELECT 
    b.[Page ID],
    ISNULL(b.[Page Group],'Other Landing Page') AS [Landing Page Group],
    ISNULL(c.[Page Group],'Other Second Page') AS [Second Page Group],
    ISNULL(d.[Page Group],'Other Page') AS [Page Path Group],
    a.*

FROM [mychoice-data-b9BwZvd] a 


LEFT OUTER JOIN [mychoice-pagedims] b 
ON 
   (a.[Landing Page Path] LIKE b.[Page ID])


LEFT OUTER JOIN [mychoice-pagedims] c 
ON 
   (a.[Second Page Path] LIKE c.[Page ID])


LEFT OUTER JOIN [mychoice-pagedims] d 
ON 
   a.[Page Path] LIKE d.[Page ID] 
   WHERE a.[Page Path] IS NOT NULL
```

I've tried `IF(EXISTS`, but whatever I do I get an error 'Invalid column name 'Page Path''.

Comment: is [mychoice-data-b9BwZvd] generated at runtime? is this why you don't know which columns exist or not?

Comment: I'm trying to create a sql querythen I can run on different data tables (which may have different columns) and only change the names of the tables (I'm actually going to use this query to pull data into PowerPivot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that in a single query, a way I suggest you to use is something like this:

```
if (
    select COUNT(*) 
    from sys.objects so 
    inner join sys.columns col 
    on so.object_id = col.object_id 
    where so.type = 'U' and so.name = 'tablename' and col.name = 'colname'
) > 0

-- column exists -> write select with the join

else

-- column does not exist, don't include the join
```

Comment: Thank you, I have opted to create the query I need using Excel based on other integration I have. Helpful to know it can't be done in one query using SQL alone.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. The database schema isn't supposed to change under your hands, so the application should know it and only query tables and columns that exist.

If it's at all possible you should change your database schema so you the tables you need to run the query on are not slightly different or even better yet so that you don't need to run it on multiple tables at all. Probably by combining the information in a single table with column indicating it's origin.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE 
    @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)='
SELECT 
    b.[Page ID],
    ISNULL(b.[Page Group],''Other Landing Page'') AS [Landing Page Group],
    ISNULL(c.[Page Group],''Other Second PAGE'') AS [Second Page Group],
    ISNULL(d.[Page Group],''Other Page'') AS [Page Path Group],
    a.*

FROM [mychoice-data-b9BwZvd] a 


LEFT OUTER JOIN [mychoice-pagedims] b 
ON 
   (a.[Landing Page Path] LIKE b.[Page ID])


LEFT OUTER JOIN [mychoice-pagedims] c 
ON 
   (a.[Second Page Path] LIKE c.[Page ID])


LEFT OUTER JOIN [mychoice-pagedims] d 
ON 
   '+
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM sys.columns C  
        JOIN sys.tables T ON T.object_id = C.object_id  
        LEFT JOIN   sys.schemas S ON S.Schema_id=T.Schema_id 
        WHERE 
            C.Name ='Page Path'  AND
            T.Name ='mychoice-pagedims'         
    )
    THEN    'a.[Page Path] LIKE d.[Page ID]'
    ELSE    '(1=0)'
END+'

WHERE a.[Page Path] IS NOT NULL
'
EXEC(@SQL)
```